# How to exclude Spring beans from @Configuration/scan packages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `@Configuration ExternalConfig` class from other library, I cannot modify it. I need to import it but also remove some beans from this external config.

Here is the `ExternalConfig` I CANNOT MODIFY (basically I want to remove `Bean1.class` and `Bean2.class` scanned from `com.config.external`)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.config.external"})
public class ExternalConfig {

}
```

And here is my custom config :

```
@Import(ExternalConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.config.external"}, excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value= {Bean1.class, Bean2.class})
})
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

}
```

But it does not work, `Bean1` and `Bean2` got injected into application context. Is there something I can do about it ?

Comment: Do you have the same result without using @Import... ?

Comment: I need to use @Import, ExternalConfig has some beans I want to import